# Rollout: no matches for kind "Rollout" in version "argoproj.io/v1alpha1"

Tags: kubernetes, devops, istio, canary-deployment, argocd

I am new to ArgoCD and I get the following error:

```
error: unable to recognize "rollout.yaml": no matches for kind "Rollout" in version "argoproj.io/v1alpha1"
```

The contents of my rollout.yaml file:

```
apiVersion: argoproj.io/v1alpha1
kind: Rollout
metadata:
  name: istio-rollout
  namespace: imo
spec:
  revisionHistoryLimit: 2
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: details
  template:
    metadata:
      annotations:
        sidecar.istio.io/inject: "true"
      labels:
        app: details
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: istio-rollout
        image: imo/employee:23
        ports:
        - name: http
          containerPort: 80
          protocol: TCP
  strategy:
    canary:
      canaryService: istio-rollout-canary
      stableService: istio-rollout-stable
      trafficRouting:
        istio:
          virtualService:
            name: customerinfo
            routes:
            - primary
      steps:
      - setWeight: 10
      - pause: {}
      - setWeight: 20
      - pause: {duration: 20s}
      - setWeight: 30
      - pause: {duration: 20s}
      - setWeight: 40
      - pause: {duration: 20s}
      - setWeight: 50
      - pause: {duration: 20s}
      - setWeight: 60
      - pause: {duration: 20s}
      - setWeight: 70
      - pause: {duration: 20s}
      - setWeight: 80
      - pause: {duration: 20s}
      - setWeight: 90
      - pause: {duration: 20s}
```

When I do a `kubectl apply -f rollout.yaml` or deploy it using 'ArgoCD UI' I get this error.
[image]

Istio and ArgoCD pods are running in my cluster setup.

K8's Version: 1.20

Docker: 20.10.5

Cluster Setup: Kubeadm

Answer (score 4):

Argo Rollouts is an own project and not part of Argo CD.
See https://argoproj.github.io/argo-rollouts/FAQ/

Comment: Thanks a lot. I installed Argo Rollout in my cluster and it works properly.